# Grpc Advantages Over Rest Apis

Tags: rest, grpc

What are the advantages of `grpc` protocol over `rest` apis?
When I googled, I came across this two points:

1. `json` vs. `stubs`
2. `grpc` is based on `http/2` where as `rest` is based on `http/1`.

I couldn't understand exactly how this is beneficial?

Can someone also helps me out with how `grpc` works and what are the advantages of using it over `rest` api and explain the above two points?

Thanks.

Comment: They both have their own advantages and disadvantages. Grpc's advantage over rest: json message is loosely typed, whereas stub message is strongly typed. Json is text based, whereas stub messages is binary based on the wire. Rest does not support bidirectional streaming/async invocation/flow control, whereas grpc does.

Comment: gRPC largely follows HTTP semantics over HTTP/2 but we explicitly allow for full-duplex streaming. We diverge from typical REST conventions as we use static paths for performance reasons during call dispatch as parsing call parameters from paths, query parameters, and payload body add latency and complexity. We have also formalized a set of errors that we believe are more directly applicable to API use cases than the HTTP status codes. 
PS: I have copied from the official site. [https://grpc.io/faq/]

Comment: I don't think this can be answered, because REST means so many things to many people.  I don't anyone can make a comparison that most people agree with, because they don't agree what REST is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First about the payload data : 
REST uses JSON, it is text and large
gRPC uses Protocol buffer to serialize payload data, it is binary and small

Second about the protocol :
REST uses HTTP/1 by default (but today we can use HTTP/2 in REST)
gRPC uses HTTP/2, it is much faster than HTTP/1.1

Comment: This is not correct, REST! ​​= JSON. You could use XML and if you follow the Roy Fielding dissertation it could still be a RESTful API. gRPC uses protocol buffers by default, but it can also be used with JSON.

Comment: In general REST uses JSON. But it can convey xml, string, binary, ...